# Input element losing it's focus after key press when it's controlled from outside the Modal (which uses Portal)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Solved] My input component is losing focus as soon as I press any key only when its value is controlled from outside the portal

> NOTE: I am sorry. While writing this, I found the problem in my code, but I decided to post this anyway

[Reason] I was inlining the `close` function, so the `useEffect` hook got triggered every time `close` changed when the component was rendered again due to state changes and thus calling the `activeElement.blur()` on each keystroke.

### Portal

```
const root = document.getElementById('root')
const modalRoot = document.getElementById('modal-root')

const Portal = ({ children, className, drawer = false }) => {
  const element = React.useMemo(() => document.createElement('div'), [])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    element.className = clsx('modal', className)
    modalRoot.appendChild(element)

    return () => {
      modalRoot.removeChild(element)
    }
  }, [element, className])

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, element)
}
```

### Modal

```
const Modal = (props) => {
  const { children, show = false, close, className } = props
  const backdrop = React.useRef(null)

  const handleTransitionEnd = React.useCallback(() => setActive(show), [show])

  const handleBackdropClick = React.useCallback(
    ({ target }) => target === backdrop.current && close(),
    []
  )

  const handleKeyUp = React.useCallback(
    ({ key }) => ['Escape'].includes(key) && close(),
    []
  )

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (backdrop.current) {
      window.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp)
    }

    if (show) {
      root.setAttribute('inert', 'true')
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'

      document.activeElement.blur?.() // ! CULPRIT
    }

    return () => {
      root.removeAttribute('inert')
      document.body.style.overflow = 'auto'
      window.removeEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp)
    }
  }, [show, close])

  return (
    <>
      {show && (
        <Portal className={className}>
          <div
            ref={backdrop}
            onClick={handleBackdropClick}
            onTransitionEnd={handleTransitionEnd}
            className={clsx('backdrop', show && 'active')}>
            <div className="content">{children}</div>
          </div>
        </Portal>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

### Custom Textfield

```
const TextField = React.forwardRef(
  ({ label, className, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <div className={clsx('textfield', className)}>
        {label && <label>{label}</label>}
        <input ref={ref} {...props} />
      </div>
    )
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was inlining the close function, so the useEffect hook got triggered every time close changed when the component was rendered again due to state changes and thus calling the activeElement.blur() on each keystroke.

In Modal.jsx

```
...
 React.useEffect(() => {
    ...

    if (show) {
      root.setAttribute('inert', 'true')
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'

      document.activeElement.blur?.() // ! CULPRIT
    }

    ...
  }, [show, close]) // as dependency
...
```

```
 <Modal
   show={show}
   close={() => setShow(false)} // this was inlined
   className="some-modal"
>
   ...
</Modal>
```

### TAKEAWAY

- Do not inline functions
- Usually there is no reason to pass a function (pointer) as dependency